# How to prove $\models (\Box A \lor \Box B) \equiv (\Box (\Box A \lor \Box B))$?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

May I please ask how to prove:

$\models (\Box A \lor \Box B) \equiv (\Box (\Box A \lor \Box B))$ is true in any $K$-$\rho \tau$ model.

$K$-$\rho \tau$ model means a $K$-model which is reflexive and transitive. $K$ represents the basic modal logic system. So $K$-$\rho \tau$ is a normal modal logic system.

$\rho$  - reflexivity

$\tau$ - transitivity

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you know how to interpret the sentence you gave in a model?

Comment: I know that I need to prove both directions and I kind of understand the statement. But I just have some problems with writing out a formal proof.

Comment: Would you know how to go about proving something simpler, like $\models \square A \to \square\square A$? Why do you run into difficulty for this sentence?

Comment: May I please ask you to write a little bit of the proof for me so that I can have a better understanding? Thanks so much.

Comment: @ButterMath: What methods/theorems are you allowed to use in your assumed homework assignment?